# A dictionary inside of a dictionary in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dictionary, hashtable, enumeration

So, I'm rather new to PowerShell and just can't figure out how to use the arrays/lists/hashtables. I basically want to do the following portrayed by Python:

```
entries = {
    'one' : {
        'id': '1',
        'text': 'ok'
    },
    'two' : {
        'id': '2',
        'text': 'no'
    }
}

for entry in entries:
    print(entries[entry]['id'])
```

Output:

> 1

> 2

---

But how does this work in PowerShell? I've tried the following:

```
$entries = @{
    one = @{
        id = "1";
        text = "ok"
    };
    two = @{
        id = "2";
        text = "no"
    }
}
```

And now I can't figure out how to access the information.

```
foreach ($entry in $entries) {
   Write-Host $entries[$entry]['id']
}
```

> => Error

Comment: You can loop through the `.Keys` property of your hash, or you can use `.GetEnumerator()`

Comment: (I suggest accepting Mathias' answer, as it directly answers your question and provides helpful general techniques).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerShell prevents implicit iteration over dictionaries to avoid accidental "unrolling".

You can work around this and loop through the contained key-value pairs by calling `GetEnumerator()` explicitly:

```
foreach($kvp in $entries.GetEnumerator()){
    Write-Host $kvp.Value['id']
}
```

For something closer to the python example, you can also extract the key values and iterate over those:

```
foreach($key in $entries.get_Keys()){
    Write-Host $entries[$key]['id']
}
```

---

Note: You'll find that iterating over `$entries.Keys` works too, but I strongly recommend *never* using that, because PowerShell resolves dictionary keys via property access, so you'll get unexpected behavior if the dictionary contains an entry with the key `"Keys"`:

```
$entries = @{
    Keys = 'a','b'
    a = 'discoverable'
    b = 'also discoverable'
    c = 'you will never find me'
}

foreach($key in $entries.Keys){ # suddenly resolves to just `'a', 'b'`
    Write-Host $entries[$key]
}
```

You'll see only the output:

```
discoverable
also discoverable
```

Not the `Keys` or `c` entries

Comment: It is unfortunate that about_Hash_Tables doesn't mention `Get_Keys()`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for volunteering for the documentation effort ;-)

Comment: This is a good candidate for a canonical answer covering hashtable/dictionary entry enumeration. Can I suggest mentioning the term "hashtable" / "hash table" in the answer, and perhaps also the `IDictionary` interface as the common denominator?
As for the backstory behind why an entry with key `Keys` unfortunately shadows the type-native `.Keys` property (ditto for `Values`), see [GitHub issue #7758](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7758). Note that, by contrast, the member-enumeration feature gets it right and gives precedence to type-native properties.

Comment: As for the documentation effort: An alternative to `.get_Keys()` / `.get_Values()`  is `.PSBase.Keys` / `.PSBase.Values`, and `.PSBase.Keys` _is_ already mentioned in [about_Hash_Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables): "If the key name collides with one of the property names of the HashTable type, you can use `PSBase` to access those properties. For example, if the key name is `keys` and you want to return the collection of Keys, use this syntax: `$hashtable.PSBase.Keys`"  /cc @SantiagoSquarzon

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71051174/45375) with a more concise alternative that takes advantage of [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375):

```sh
# Implicitly loops over all entry values and from each 
# gets the 'Id' entry value from the nested hashtable. 
$entries.Values.Id  # -> 2, 1
```

<sup>Note: As with `.Keys` vs. `.get_Keys()`, you may choose to routinely use `.get_Values()` instead of `.Values` to avoid problems with keys literally named `Values`.</sup>